# Error: inject() must be called from an injection context but can't find origin

Tags: angular, firebase, inject, injectable

I'm using angularfire's authentication service to register and login users to my application but when I trigger the register or signin method, I get the following error: **Error: inject() must be called from an injection context**

I've tried setting preserveSymlinks in my angular.json file to be true, but still no avail.

How is it that my register and signin methods are calling inject(), and why is it not working?

Please find my relevant files below:

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app",
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "assets"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/global.scss"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "progress": false
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/assets",
                "output": "/assets"
              }
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "progress": false,
              "watch": false
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            },
            "ci": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:ci"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:page": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

**login.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth'
import {auth} from 'firebase/app'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore/public_api';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
  userEmail: string = ""
  password: string = ""
  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
    public user: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  async login() {
    //gives access to user email and password
    const {userEmail, password} = this
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, password)
      // if (result.user) {
      //   this.user.setUser({
      //     email: userEmail,
      //     uid: result.user.uid
      //   })
        this.router.navigate(['/tabs'])
      
      
    } catch (error) {
        console.dir(error)
        if (error.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
          console.log("User not found!")
        }
    }
  }

}
```

**register.page.ts**

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore'
import { UserService } from '../services/user.model';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {
  userEmail: string = ""
  password: string = ""
  cpassword: string = ""
  
  firstName: string = ""
  lastName: string = ""
  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,
    public user: UserService,
    private afs: AngularFirestore
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async register() {
    const { 
      userEmail, 
      password, 
      cpassword, 
      firstName, 
      lastName} = this
    if(password !== cpassword) {
      return console.log("Please reconcile passwords")
    }
    try {
      const result =  await this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, password)
      
      // sets user information in firestore
      this.afs.doc('users/${result.user.uid}').set({
        userEmail,
        firstName,
        lastName
      })

      this.user.setUser({
        email: userEmail,
        uid: result.user.uid
      })
      console.log(result)
      this.router.navigate(['/tabs'])
      
      
    } catch(error) {
        console.dir(error)
    }
    
  }
}
```

**user.model.ts**

```
interface User {
    uid ?: string
    firstName ?: string
    lastName ?: string
    email ?: string
    displayName ?: string
}

export class UserService {
    private user: User
    constructor() {

    }
    setUser(user: User) {
        console.log(user.displayName)
        this.user = user
    }
    getUser() {
        return this.user.uid
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "paths": { 
      "@angular/": 
      [ "../node_modules/@angular/" ] 
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the below line in compilerOptions section of tsconfig.app.json of the angular application.

```json
"paths": { "@angular/*": [ "../node_modules/@angular/*" ] }
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I added the tsconfig.app.json above for reference. @surendra